# PySide Installation

Tags: windows, python-3.x, configuration, installation

I'm trying to install the PySide on python 3.5 (32-bit) on windows 10, I installed the pip, it's ok, but when I run the command 'easy_install' at cmd, shows this: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Subtitle:** "-U" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

When I run the command 'import easy_install' on python's console, it's ok nothing is shown here, but When I run "import PySide' shows the error 'ImportError: No module named 'PySide'"

Anyone knows why it occurs?

Comment: Because you typed `> ` before the command. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience using easy_install, but I wonder if you should try `--upgrade` instead of `-U`.  Also, don't know if you want the upgrade flag at all if you don't have the package installed in the first place.

You mentioned you have pip installed, so you can install PySide like this:

```
python -m pip install PySide
```

Or if you are trying to upgrade PySide:

```
python -m pip install PySide
```

Note that you'll need python in your PATH environment variable, otherwise you'll need to provide the full path to the python interpreter, wherever that may be on your system:

```
C:/python27/python.exe -m pip install --upgrade PySide
```